# Putting \the\wd inside a group makes it produce 0.0pt

Tags: boxes, dimensions, registers

The following is a minimal example demonstrating some behavior of latex that I don't understand. I'm using xelatex, but the behavior in pdflatex seems to be the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\myboxregister
\newwrite\outputfile
\openout\outputfile=test.txt

\begin{document}

{ %%% Removing the {...} fixes the code.

\savebox{\myboxregister}{aaa}%
\usebox{\myboxregister}%
\write\outputfile{\the\wd\myboxregister}%

} %%% Removing the {...} fixes the code.

\closeout\outputfile

\end{document}
```

The output to the file test.txt is 0.0pt, which is not the correct width for the box register. If I comment out the curly braces as indicated in the comments, the output is the correct value of about 15 pt.

How would I fix this? I want to be able to do this kind of thing inside various environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\write` is a delayed action that happens when the page is shipped out, by which time the group is ended. You can use `\immediate\write` to write to the file at that point, In that case you should also use `\immediate\openout`

Comment: Thanks! You're very generous with your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the contents of `\write` at point of usage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\myboxregister
\newwrite\outputfile
\openout\outputfile=\jobname-wd.txt

\begin{document}

{ %%% Removing the {...} fixes the code.

\savebox{\myboxregister}{aaa}%
\usebox{\myboxregister}%
\write\outputfile\expandafter{\the\wd\myboxregister}%

} %%% Removing the {...} fixes the code.

\closeout\outputfile

\end{document}
```

Contents of the written file:

```
15.00005pt
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work as a way of fixing my minimal example, but when I try it in my actual code, it doesn't work. I could try to figure out by bisection why there's the difference in behavior, but the method given in David Carlisle's answer is working for my purposes. Maybe others will find this preferable.

Comment: @BenCrowell If you show a real use case…